# Use recursion to get all combinations of a collection with certain parameters

Tags: java, recursion

I would like to find a way to use recursion to generate all unique combinations of elements from a collection with a few parameters... 1) i want to be able define the size of a single combo. 2) i want to be able to provide my own elements from the collection (less than the size provided) to generate all combinations that include the elements i've provided.

Since the might have been confusing an input would look like this...

input: (set of elements, size of a single combination, provided elements (from 0 to the size -1)

output: set of all possible combinations (order is irrelevant)

For example let's say i have letters a-z as the collection of elements i provide. Let's also say i want the size of a combination to be 5. Let's also say i provide "FG" to the method.

```
getCombos(Set<V> collection, int size, Set<V> provided)

return Set<Set<V>> combos
```

Here's how it would look with input,

```
getCombos(alphabet, 5, myChars)
```

This method should return 24*23*22 (12144) unique 5 letter combinations that include F and G.

Here's what i tried, i feel like this is probably way off.

```
public static <V> HashSet<HashSet<V>> getCombos(HashSet<V> base, HashSet<V> elements, int size) {
    HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos = new HashSet<HashSet<V>>();
    HashSet<V> curr = new HashSet<V>(base);
    recur(curr, combos, base, elements, size);
    return combos;

}

public static <V> void recur(HashSet<V> curr, HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos, HashSet<V> base, HashSet<V> elements, int size) {
    if (curr.size() == size)
        combos.add(curr);
    else
        for (V v : elements) {
            curr.add(v);
            recur(curr, combos, base, elements, size);
            // This part below is where i feel like i'm going wrong and i'm not sure what to do
            curr = dupe(base);
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I added what i've tried.

Comment: Does `F` and `G` can be at any slots in your result? E.G., Are both of `FABCG`, `GCFWA` good outputs?

Comment: @Top.Deck Yes, order is irrelevant

Comment: Then it seems the number of combination of your example will be `P(5, 2)*P(24-2, 3)` which is `184800`. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was almost right, you just had a few logical mistakes in there. This hopefully should work the way you want it to:

```
public static <V> HashSet<HashSet<V>> getCombos(HashSet<V> base, HashSet<V> elements, int size) {
    HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos = new HashSet<HashSet<V>>();
    HashSet<V> inner = dupe(base);
    inner.removeAll(elements);
    recur(elements, combos, inner, size);
    return combos;

}

public static <V> HashSet<V> dupe(HashSet<V> orig) {
    return new HashSet<V>(orig);
}

public static <V> void recur(HashSet<V> curr, HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos, HashSet<V> base, int size) {
    if (curr.size() == size) {
        combos.add(dupe(curr));
    } else {
        HashSet<V> inner = dupe(base);
        for (V v : base) {
            inner.remove(v);
            curr.add(v);
            recur(curr, combos, inner, size);
            curr.remove(v);
        }
    }
}
```

For the by you given example of letters it will give correctly 2024 since your number of 12144 contains 6 reorderings of each combination for the three letters added to FG.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... doesn't populate the HashSet<HashSet<>> with anything

Comment: @BenArnao I used `HashSet<String> base = new HashSet<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
   base.add((char) (97 + i) + "");
  }
  HashSet<String> elements = new HashSet<String>();
  elements.add("f");
  elements.add("g");
  int size = 5;
  HashSet<HashSet<String>> combos = getCombos(base, elements, size);
  System.out.println(combos.size());` to call it and it returned 2024

Comment: My bad, seems to work you're right. Thanks for the help